# Why is Jquery UI open/close not working in ASP.Net MVC program

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using the ASP.Net template in visual studio and I am trying to get a Modal popup on the Index page to work, I wrote some code in java only and it works just fine. If I set autoOpen true I see what I expect to see and I am able to close the popup with the X button but the close function does not work when you select the OK button or the cancel button. If I set autoOpen to false and I can click on the open button nothing happens, it does not open. I have tried many thing and I have searched the internet for answers.
The only file that is important is the Index.cshtml file everything else is the same as when you start a new ASP.Net MVC project:

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index Page";
}

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="message" title="Chuck Norris">
    <p> Is the only one to stop this virus</p>
</div>

<button id="opener"> Open Window </button>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#message').css('background', 'red');
    $('#message').css('color', 'white');
    $('#message').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            ok: function () {
                $("#message").dialog('close');
            },
            cancel: function () {
                $('message').dialog('close');
            }
        },
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });
    $('#opener').on('click', function () {        
        $('#message').dialog("open");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It would be so simple if you use popup modal of `bootstrap`

Comment: Incorrect syntax: `$('message').dialog('close');` this should be `$('#message').dialog('close');`

Comment: Changing the OK button to  $('#message').dialog('close'); did not work either but the X still works.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue as you described it. I used the following test.

```js
$('#message').css('background', 'red');
$('#message').css('color', 'white');
$('#message').dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    ok: function() {
      $("#message").dialog('close');
    },
    cancel: function() {
      $('#message').dialog('close');
    }
  },
  show: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  }
});
$('#opener').on('click', function() {
  $('#message').dialog("open");
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="message" title="Chuck Norris">
  <p> Is the only one to stop this virus</p>
</div>

<button id="opener"> Open Window </button>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The modal popups up if I have autoOpen set to true. Clicking the OK button on the modal does not close the modal. I am using IE, Firefox and Chrome and all are doing the same thing.

Comment: @user2697296 when I click OK or Cancel it closes as expected. Testing in FireFox.

Comment: Are you using VS 2019 ?

Comment: @user2697296 am using FF  v 78.0.2

Comment: OK, thank you for the information. I posted that I got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking to solve this problem:
in the Index.cshtml file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<link href="~/Content/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<h2>To Stop the virus open the modal</h2>
<p></p>
<button id="modal-opener">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="message" title="Chuck Norris">
    <p>This is the only way to stop the virus</p>
</div>
<script>

    $(function () {
        $("#message").css('background', 'red');
        $('#message').css('color', 'white');
        $("#message").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            height: 280,
            show: {
                effect: "shake",
                duration: 100
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            },
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
        //$('#message').dialog('open');
        $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
            $('#message').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the _layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Content/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -ASP.NET Testing Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

IN the home controller:

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        
    }
```